# Unable to Pass a space in Odata parameter while automating an API using playwright

Tags: odata, playwright

I am trying to automate an oData API using Playwright typescript. Via postman it works fine but not via playwright. The issue is the space

postman - getuserbyusername?$filter=username%20eq%20%272006040004%27

playwright - getuserbyusername?%24filter=username+eq+%272006040006%27
This is by passing space

in postman for the odata param
key => $filter
value => username eq '2006040004'

I tried adding the + on either side of eq as well as \ and %2B nothing worked. Any other way. I don't want to install any libraries related to odata

Comment: Happy to take a look. Can you share your actual  code formatted please? So i can check it out

Comment: const requestParameters = {
    $filter: `username eq '${participant}'`
  }

const participantDetails = await actor.request.get(
      `${process.env.PLAYWRIGHT_APIM_BASE_URL}xxxx/xxxx/getuserbyusername`,
      {
        headers: requestHeaders,
        params: requestParameters,
      },
    )